# Java: remove fixed number of characters at the start and the end from a string

Tags: java, string, parsing, character

I'm dealing with strings that differ in size but I know that there will always be the same number of characters at the beginning and end. e.g.

```
String i = "id3-jfhd3udj-endid";
String i = "id7-fdl3-endid";
String i = "id1-lkjf348hosjsldf-endid";
```

Is there a way (like a method in the String class) that would allow me to parse the string every time, removing the front characters and the back characters?

Also, what if the string contains two '-'?:

```
String i = "id3-t-jfhd3udj-t-endid";
```

Thanks

Comment: String.substring(int,int) will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, what if the string contains two '-'?:

```
String i = "id3-t-jfhd3udj-t-endid";
```

As long as the string contains an even number of dashes, and the substring that you want is in the middle, this code will work.

```
    public String extractString(String s) {
        String[] parts = s.split("-");
        return parts[parts.length / 2];
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

> I know that there will always be the same number of characters at the
>   begging and end

Just use the [`substring(int beginIndex,
               int endIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method :

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at
>   index endIndex - 1.

```
i.substring(4, i.length()-6)
```

Alternatively, if you know that the part you want is always between the two `'-'`, you can use :

```
i.substring(i.indexOf('-')+1, i.lastIndexOf('-'))
```

The last solution will always work whatever the number of characters at the
beggining and end are, while the first one will only work for your specific case.

Comment: what if the string contains two '-'?:

"id3-t-jfhd3udj-t-endid"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring() method to extract the required string .

Syntax: `substring(int startIndex,int endIndex);`

```
int index1= i.indexOf("-");
int index2= i.lastIndexOf("-");
i=i.substring(index1+1,index2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Then use the `String.substring` method:

```
string.substring(string.indexOf("-")+1, string.lastIndexOf("-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always in that exact format (with the '-'s), the easiest [probably not the most efficient though] way to get the middle section of the string is probably `i.split("-")[1]`.

If not, you could use `i.substring(4, i.length() - 6))`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach

```
String i = "id1-lkjf348hosjsldf-endid";
System.out.println(i);
if (i.contains("-")) { // check for '-'
  i = i.substring(1+i.indexOf('-'), i.lastIndexOf('-')); // first dash to last dash.
}
System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is always in the form of `<prefix>-<content>-<suffix>` (contains two '`-`') then you can try this:

```
String content = string.split("-")[1];
```